# How to get a margin right value of a centered div (margin 0 auto) in mozilla

Tags: jquery

I tried the following code and it works on Chrome, Opera, IE9+ but not on Mozilla

HTML

```
<div class="centered"></div>
<span class="value"></span>
```

CSS

```
.centered {width:300px;height:300px;background:yellow;margin:0 auto;}
```

JS

```
$('.value').text($('.centered').css('margin-right'));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eo3jdm3y/

I just want to get the value of margin right of a centered element(with margin: 0 auto)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eo3jdm3y/1/)

```
$('.offsetLeft').text($('.centered').offset().left);
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work because you're looking for a CSS value. Which is set to auto. Instead you should look for the actual pixel value. In jQuery you could use the [`.offset()` method](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

```
$('.value').text($('.centered').offset().left)
//left will be the same as right, since it's set to auto
```